# Publish web application to simple folder (not IIS virtual directory)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msbuild

`Hi all. I'm trying to build one of the web application's projects through the console by calling msbuild.

I use .net framework 4.5 and msbuild CLI.
I'm building a project on a separate machine that doesn't need installed IIS. After publish i'm going to deploy application files manually.

At the end of the build, an error pops up

ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section
registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Those. the directory where the built files are placed is not an IIS virtual directory.
Due to the fact that the project is built on a separate machine, this is correct.

Actually the question is - is it possible to publish all project files - with the web.config file, !app.offline, etc., but in a regular folder just as a set of files for further transfer to another machine? In fact, turn off the check that the directory with the output files is not targeted by IIS.

Now i use msbuild command:
`& msbuild.exe MySolution.sln /t:MyProject /p:Configuration=Release /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile /p:Platform="Any CPU" /nr:false /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=true /p:publishUrl=./Publish/myProject`

Publish profile:
`<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"> <PropertyGroup> <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod> <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider> <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration> <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform> <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish /> <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish> <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data> <publishUrl>C:\dev\publish\myProject</publishUrl> <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles> <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish> <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable> <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols> <WDPMergeOption>MergeAllPagesAndControlToASingleAssembly</WDPMergeOption> <UseMerge>True</UseMerge> <ContentAssemblyName>Compiled</ContentAssemblyName> </PropertyGroup> </Project>`

**Try**: execute msbuild command with publish profile from question's description
**Expected**: The application files will be built (including the web.config for the specified configuration and !app.offline) and placed in the specified folder. This will not check that the folder is an IIS virtual directory and will not throw an error after publishing is complete.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by deleting the parameter
`/p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish`